# Methods of deriving $\sum^n_{x=0} xr^{x-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

To calculate this sum, we can differentiate $\sum^n_{x=0} r^{x}$:

$$ \sum^n_{x=0} xr^{x-1} = \frac{d}{dr} \sum^n_{x=0} r^{x} =   \frac{d}{dr} \left(\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}\right) = \frac{(n+1)r^{n}}{r-1} - \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{(r-1)^2} 
$$

However, this disagrees with the method of factoring out $r^{-1}$:

$$ \sum^n_{x=0} xr^{x-1} = \frac{1}{r}\sum^n_{x=0} xr^{x} = \frac 1r \left( \frac{ nr^{n+1}}{r-1} -\frac{r^{n+1}-r}{(r-1)^2}  \right) = \frac{nr^n}{r-1} - \frac{r^n-1}{(r-1)^2}
$$

Which of the two methods should be used, or did I apply them incorrectly?

Comment: Using $x$ for discrete index variable is a bit unusual and can be confusing to some... in this case $\sum^n_{x=0} xr^{x-1} = \frac{d}{dx} \sum^n_{x=0} r^{x}$ is incorrect (actually $\frac{d}{dx} \sum^n_{x=0} r^{x} =0$), you should be differentianting w.r.t $r$, or switch variables to more common $\sum^n_{r=0} rx^{r-1} = \frac{d}{dx} \sum^n_{r=0} x^{r}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two expressions are the same:
$$\begin{align} \frac{(n+1)r^{n}}{r-1} - \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{(r-1)^2} &= \frac{nr^{n}}{r-1} + \frac{r^n}{r-1}- \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{(r-1)^2}\\ &= \frac{nr^{n}}{r-1} + \frac{r^n(r-1)}{(r-1)^2}- \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{(r-1)^2}\\ &= \frac{nr^n}{r-1} - \frac{r^n-1}{(r-1)^2}. \end{align}$$